# AsyncLocalStorage loose context in mongoose hooks POST save

Tags: node.js, mongoose, local-storage, asyncstorage, async-hooks

**How to do to maintain the same context in all flow ?**

**Why the AsyncHooks context is loose inside the Schema.post('save') but not in Schema.pre('save')?**

Please, look the testes-mongoose branch and execute **yarn example:mongoose**. GIT HUB Source:
https://github.com/almerindo/traceability/tree/testes-mongoose

**File: examples/mongoose/schema/traceability.schema.ts**

```
TraceabilitySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const context = ContextAsyncHooks.getContext();
  console.info({context})
  Logger.info('Has This log a trackId in PRE SAVE? ');
  next();
});

TraceabilitySchema.post('save', function(doc) {
  const context = ContextAsyncHooks.getContext();
  console.info({context})
  Logger.info('Has This log a trackId in POST SAVE? ');
});
```

The Output is:

```
{"message":"BEGIN OF ALL","level":"info","trackId":"952ac121-5a8c-46b5-a054-52b8185c7023","timestamp":"2021-04-27T11:54:39.756Z"}
{ context: { trackId: '952ac121-5a8c-46b5-a054-52b8185c7023' } }
{"message":"Has This log a trackId in PRE SAVE? ","level":"info","trackId":"952ac121-5a8c-46b5-a054-52b8185c7023","timestamp":"2021-04-27T11:54:39.764Z"}
Conexão estabelecida -Mongo {"useNewUrlParser":true,"authSource":"admin","useUnifiedTopology":true}
{ context: undefined }
{"message":"Has This log a trackId in POST SAVE? ","level":"info","timestamp":"2021-04-27T11:54:39.794Z"}
{"message":"END OF ALL","level":"info","trackId":"952ac121-5a8c-46b5-a054-52b8185c7023","timestamp":"2021-04-27T11:54:39.795Z"}
```

> Note: Only the output inside MONGOOSE HOOKS POST SAVE the context is
> NULL

Comment: Did you note that your code works with an `update` and not with a `create`?

Comment: Not yet!
But I really did understand why asyncHooks lose the context only in TraceabilitySchema.post